# Переклад слова "reset"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Намагаюся перекласти гарно слово ***reset***, не в значенні *перезавантажувати щось*, а в значенні *відновити початкові параметри/конфігурацію; стерти користувацькі налаштування, повернути/відновити початкові/попередні значення... і т.д.*

Декілька прикладів використання:

> reset the settings
>   reset the configuration
>   reset the system
>   reset a program version
>   reset current progress

Проте, всі можливі варіанти, котрі я знайшов, звучать як погана російська калька, хоча частина цих варіантів використовується в офіційних локалізаціях багатьох пристроїв.

> скидати до стандартних налаштувань
>   скидати налаштування до стандартних значень
>   скидати налаштування
>   скидати до заводських налаштувань

Ці варіанти заслуговують на довіру? Є ще якісь варіанти? Є якийсь усталений переклад? 
Відповідь **повинна** бути канонічною.

Comment: *відновити початкові параметри/конфігурацію* (restore), *стерти користувацькі налаштування* (erase), *повернути початкові/попередні значення* (reset в значенні to cause a device to return to a former condition)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Будь ласка, якщо ви можете це обгрунтувати - розмістіть це як відповідь(бажано з посиланнями на якісь джерела).

Comment: Хто встановлює канонічність в перекладах тих чи інших слів?

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/what-is-a-canonical-answer

Comment: Про мене, відповідь має бути прекрасно обгрунтована на основі якихось авторитетних джерел, аби сформувати стандарт для перекладу усіх пов'язаних словосполучень та єдину відповідь для всіх пов'язаних дублікатів(зараз вже є 1, в майбутньому може бути більше).

Comment: Думаю, що слово народилось від "re-set" - **пере-встановити**

Comment: @wowkin2 Питання не про походження слова.

Comment: @improbable я до того, що воно мало б найкраще передавати сенс.

Comment: @wowkin2 це суб'єктивізм у чистому вигляді, а на сайтах SE він взагалі заборонений та і нікому не потрібний.

Comment: Чому зникають відповіді?